# How to launch an activity (java class) from a button of a home fragment from another package in android studio (java)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXbfK.jpg)

I want that a button on the HomeFragment launchs the TestApp activity.

I tried this, but didn't work;

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        button = (Button) button.findViewById(R.id.button);
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        final TextView textView = binding.textHome;
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), textView::setText);


        return root;
    }

    public void openAc(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestApp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
```

Comment: You need to add an OnClickListener to the button in your onCreateView method to make it perform an action when clicked.

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't work"?